# If $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)/(f)$ is reduced, does $m_X = (f)$ hold?

Tags: differential-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function, $X$ be its zero set, $X=\{x \in\mathbb{R}^n\mid f(x)=0\}$, and $m_X = \{ g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\mid g(X)=0\}.$

In general, $m_X$ doesn't coincide with $(f)$ (for example, when $f=x^2$, $x\in m_X$ but $x\notin (f)$ ).

If $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)/(f)$ is reduced, does $m_X=(f)$ hold?

Comment: What if $n=2$ and $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$?

Comment: ah...this equality rarely hold